# ScriptDB Group By

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to group result by any data of the records stored in the DB ?
I have readed google-apps-script documentation with no luck.

I've:

```
userLogActivity = {
  registry_type: "userLog",
  user_email: activeUser.getEmail(),
  user_loginId: activeUser.getUserLoginId(),
  user_urlAccess: activePage.getUrl(),
  user_date: currentDate.getTime()
};
```

And I retrieve these records like this:

```
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var results = db.query({}).sortBy("user_date", db.DESCENDING);
```

but now I need to group by user_date.

A count() function would be handfull too...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ScriptDb doesn't have native groupBy, but you can mimic it very easily as such:

```
var results = db.query({}).sortBy("user_date", db.DESCENDING);
var grouped = {};
while (result.hasNext()) {
  var obj  = result.next();
  var key = obj.user_date; 
  grouped[key] = grouped[key] || [];
  grouped[key].push(obj);
}
```

Count, however, is built in. For count, just replace `db.query({})` with `db.count({})`

Comment: The problem with your answers is always the same: they are so smart and seem so obvious that it takes me a week to understand it... life is unfair :-)